# Simulate SDE without error

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings, differential-equations

Let

- $d,k\in\mathbb N$;
- $\sigma\in C^1(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^{d\times k})$ be Lipschitz and $\Sigma:=\sigma\sigma^\ast$;
- $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a $k$-dimensional Brownian motion;
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$;
- $p\in C^1(\mathbb R^d)$ be positive with $$c:=\lambda^{\otimes p}<\infty p$$ and $$\mu:=\frac pc\lambda^{\otimes p};$$
- $U\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ be antisymmetric and $$b:=\frac{\Sigma+U}{2p}\nabla p+\frac12\nabla\cdot\Sigma.$$

We know that the strong solution $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ of $${\rm d}X_t=b(X_t){\rm d}t+\sigma(X_t){\rm d}W_t\tag1$$ is a Markov process and $\mu$ is invariant with respect to the transition semigroup of $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$.

> How can we simulate $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ "without error"?

Strictly speaking, this is clearly not possible, but how should we simulate from $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ in practice; i.e. how do we ensure that our simulated sample from $X_t$ is really a sample from $X_t$?

When $\sigma$ is constant, then $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a Gaussian process. Is the question easier to answer then?

In general, we need to choose a discretization method. We could use the Euler-Maruyama method or the Milstein method for this. Is the latter worth the additional computational cost?

There is also the question how the step sizes should be chosen and whether or not they should decrease to $0$.

We could additionally use a Metropolis-Hastings correction to ensure that $\mu$ is still invariant with respect to the simulated chain, but I'm not sure if this is really necessary.

When $U\ne0$, $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is nonreversible. So, I actually would not want that the chain used for simulation is reversible (which would be the case, if we use a Metropolis-Hastings correction). The paper [Irreversible Samplers from Jump and Continuous Markov Processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05973) might be applicable, but from [High-dimensional Bayesian inference via the Unadjusted Langevin Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01559) I could also imagine that vanishing step sizes are sufficient ...